# JQuery - How to get jquery to display the html code of the page its embedded on

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to write a JQuery program that will display the HTML code of the website at the bottom of the page. I'm completely lost and I don't really know what to look at to get this to work.

The whole HTML code, including

Thanks

Comment: the whole html including the `<html>` and `<head>` tags or only the `<body>` content

Comment: Do you mean to get the HTML CODE and display that code???

Comment: The whole html code that the website its linked to has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="getPageHTML()">
    <pre id="content"></pre>
    <script src="/../../../libraries/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getPageHTML() {
            var test = "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";
            console.log(test);
            $('#content').text(test);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the content of the html then add html tag:

```
"<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>"
```